# Getting error while using Logger - "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.slf4j.Logger' in your configuration."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

My code:-

import org.slf4j.Logger;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

logger.info("");

i am getting this error ->

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-13 14:38:42.998 ERROR 12884 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 2 of constructor in com.myapp.app.service.MyService required a bean of type 'org.slf4j.Logger' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.slf4j.Logger' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Remove thge `Logger` from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of a logger added as a dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or can you show us your logger dependencies?

Also there are good tutorials for logging:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-logging-intro
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging

Comment: Thank you for reply. After some research i got to know the error. The Logger was giving error because i didn't pass 2 parameters (string and error). So now instread instead of using Logger i used @log4j2 and then use log.info() to print the logs.